# C# program txtbox and combox and everything in windowform is out of place?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, label

i've created a program and it runs smooth in my pc and everything is like how it is in VS but when i run it on other pc Every textbox and label and everything is not in its correct location, they seem to be out of place from where they Were.
I tired locking but no luck too and i dont really get the correct position what i see (or made) in Visual Studio after debugging and running :( even in my pc ( but it still better than running in other pc )
Im totally lost and im so tired to re-create since it's my project and i'm running out of time.

All i want to know is why and how to lock all the labels and textbox's and everything which is in my windows form and usercontorl.

this is when making in VS

http://s9.postimage.org/rvxsa9jul/image.jpg

this is after i debug in my pc

http://s9.postimage.org/ipfhmzem5/image.jpg
i hope you guys uhnderstood my problem

And here is designer.cs on mt usercontrol.cs

do u mean the designer.cs and here it is

```
 partial class Reservation
    {
        ///  
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// 
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
```

`/// <summary> 
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Component Designer generated code

    /// <summary> 
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.Agetxt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label8 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.Addresstxt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label7 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.Occupationtxt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label6 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.PhoneNoTxt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label5 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.MarriedcomboBox = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.SexComboBox = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.LastNametxt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.FirstNametxt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label9 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.ReasonForStayingtxt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label10 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.NoOfAdultstxt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label11 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.NoOfChildrentxt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label12 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.NoOfDaysToStaytxt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.label13 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.RoomTypeComboBox = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.label14 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // Agetxt
        // 
        this.Agetxt.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left;
        this.Agetxt.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.Agetxt.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(70, 162);
        this.Agetxt.MaxLength = 3;
        this.Agetxt.Name = "Agetxt";
        this.Agetxt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 22);
        this.Agetxt.TabIndex = 15;
        // 
        // label8
        // 
        this.label8.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left;
        this.label8.AutoSize = true;
        this.label8.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label8.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 165);
        this.label8.Name = "label8";
        this.label8.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(33, 16);
        this.label8.TabIndex = 14;
        this.label8.Text = "Age";
        // 
        // Addresstxt
        // 
        this.Addresstxt.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left;
        this.Addresstxt.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.Addresstxt.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(71, 219);
        this.Addresstxt.Multiline = true;
        this.Addresstxt.Name = "Addresstxt";
        this.Addresstxt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(251, 72);
        this.Addresstxt.TabIndex = 13;
        // 
        // label7
        // 
        this.label7.AutoSize = true;
        this.label7.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label7.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(14, 234);
        this.label7.Name = "label7";
        this.label7.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(59, 16);
        this.label7.TabIndex = 12;
        this.label7.Text = "Address";
        // 
        // Occupationtxt
        // 
        this.Occupationtxt.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left;
        this.Occupationtxt.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.Occupationtxt.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(230, 192);
        this.Occupationtxt.Name = "Occupationtxt";
        this.Occupationtxt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(92, 22);
        this.Occupationtxt.TabIndex = 11;
        // 
        // label6
        // 
        this.label6.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left;
        this.label6.AutoSize = true;
        this.label6.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(161, 192);
        this.label6.Name = "label6";
        this.label6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(76, 16);
        this.label6.TabIndex = 10;
        this.label6.Text = "Occupation";
        // 
        // PhoneNoTxt
        // 
        this.PhoneNoTxt.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left;
        this.PhoneNoTxt.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.PhoneNoTxt.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(71, 189);
        this.PhoneNoTxt.MaxLength = 15;
        this.PhoneNoTxt.Name = "PhoneNoTxt";
        this.PhoneNoTxt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(74, 22);
        this.PhoneNoTxt.TabIndex = 9;
        // 
        // label5
        // 
        this.label5.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left;
        this.label5.AutoSize = true;
        this.label5.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 192);
        this.label5.Name = "label5";
        this.label5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(71, 16);
        this.label5.TabIndex = 8;
        this.label5.Text = "Phone No.";
        // 
        // MarriedcomboBox
        // 
        this.MarriedcomboBox.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left;
        this.MarriedcomboBox.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.MarriedcomboBox.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.MarriedcomboBox.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.MarriedcomboBox.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "Married",
        "Unmarried"});
        this.MarriedcomboBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(230, 130);
        this.MarriedcomboBox.Name = "MarriedcomboBox";
        this.MarriedcomboBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(92, 24);
        this.MarriedcomboBox.TabIndex = 7;
        // 
        // label4
        // 
        this.label4.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left;
        this.label4.AutoSize = true;
        this.label4.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(161, 133);
        this.label4.Name = "label4";
        this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(102, 16);
        this.label4.TabIndex = 6;
        this.label4.Text = "Marriage Status";
        // 
        // SexComboBox
        // 
        this.SexComboBox.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left;
        this.SexComboBox.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.SexComboBox.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.SexComboBox.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.SexComboBox.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "Female",
        "Male"});
        this.SexComboBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(70, 130);
        this.SexComboBox.Name = "SexComboBox";
        this.SexComboBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(74, 24);
        this.SexComboBox.Sorted = true;
        this.SexComboBox.TabIndex = 5;
        // 
        // label3
        // 
        this.label3.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left;
        this.label3.AutoSize = true;
        this.label3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(25, 133);
        this.label3.Name = "label3";
        this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(31, 16);
        this.label3.TabIndex = 4;
        this.label3.Text = "Sex";
        // 
        // LastNametxt
        // 
        this.LastNametxt.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left;
        this.LastNametxt.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.LastNametxt.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(229, 103);
        this.LastNametxt.Name = "LastNametxt";
        this.LastNametxt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(92, 22);
        this.LastNametxt.TabIndex = 3;
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this.label2.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left;
        this.label2.AutoSize = true;
        this.label2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(162, 103);
        this.label2.Name = "label2";
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(73, 16);
        this.label2.TabIndex = 2;
        this.label2.Text = "Last Name";
        // 
        // FirstNametxt
        // 
        this.FirstNametxt.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left;
        this.FirstNametxt.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.FirstNametxt.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(70, 103);
        this.FirstNametxt.Name = "FirstNametxt";
        this.FirstNametxt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(92, 22);
        this.FirstNametxt.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left;
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 103);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(73, 16);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = "First Name";
        // 
        // label9
        // 
        this.label9.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right;
        this.label9.AutoSize = true;
        this.label9.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label9.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(380, 105);
        this.label9.Name = "label9";
        this.label9.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(122, 16);
        this.label9.TabIndex = 16;
        this.label9.Text = "Reason for Staying";
        // 
        // ReasonForStayingtxt
        // 
        this.ReasonForStayingtxt.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right;
        this.ReasonForStayingtxt.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.ReasonForStayingtxt.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(483, 105);
        this.ReasonForStayingtxt.Multiline = true;
        this.ReasonForStayingtxt.Name = "ReasonForStayingtxt";
        this.ReasonForStayingtxt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(289, 94);
        this.ReasonForStayingtxt.TabIndex = 17;
        // 
        // label10
        // 
        this.label10.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right;
        this.label10.AutoSize = true;
        this.label10.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label10.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(407, 231);
        this.label10.Name = "label10";
        this.label10.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(85, 16);
        this.label10.TabIndex = 18;
        this.label10.Text = "No. Of Adults";
        // 
        // NoOfAdultstxt
        // 
        this.NoOfAdultstxt.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right;
        this.NoOfAdultstxt.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.NoOfAdultstxt.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(483, 224);
        this.NoOfAdultstxt.MaxLength = 3;
        this.NoOfAdultstxt.Name = "NoOfAdultstxt";
        this.NoOfAdultstxt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(84, 22);
        this.NoOfAdultstxt.TabIndex = 19;
        // 
        // label11
        // 
        this.label11.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right;
        this.label11.AutoSize = true;
        this.label11.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label11.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(587, 231);
        this.label11.Name = "label11";
        this.label11.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(97, 16);
        this.label11.TabIndex = 20;
        this.label11.Text = "No. Of Children";
        // 
        // NoOfChildrentxt
        // 
        this.NoOfChildrentxt.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right;
        this.NoOfChildrentxt.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.NoOfChildrentxt.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(672, 224);
        this.NoOfChildrentxt.MaxLength = 3;
        this.NoOfChildrentxt.Name = "NoOfChildrentxt";
        this.NoOfChildrentxt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 22);
        this.NoOfChildrentxt.TabIndex = 21;
        // 
        // label12
        // 
        this.label12.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right;
        this.label12.AutoSize = true;
        this.label12.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label12.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(407, 274);
        this.label12.Name = "label12";
        this.label12.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(124, 16);
        this.label12.TabIndex = 22;
        this.label12.Text = "No. Of Days to Stay";
        // 
        // NoOfDaysToStaytxt
        // 
        this.NoOfDaysToStaytxt.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right;
        this.NoOfDaysToStaytxt.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.NoOfDaysToStaytxt.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(517, 267);
        this.NoOfDaysToStaytxt.MaxLength = 3;
        this.NoOfDaysToStaytxt.Name = "NoOfDaysToStaytxt";
        this.NoOfDaysToStaytxt.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 22);
        this.NoOfDaysToStaytxt.TabIndex = 23;
        // 
        // label13
        // 
        this.label13.AutoSize = true;
        this.label13.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label13.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 311);
        this.label13.Name = "label13";
        this.label13.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 16);
        this.label13.TabIndex = 24;
        this.label13.Text = "Room Type";
        // 
        // RoomTypeComboBox
        // 
        this.RoomTypeComboBox.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.RoomTypeComboBox.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.RoomTypeComboBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(70, 308);
        this.RoomTypeComboBox.Name = "RoomTypeComboBox";
        this.RoomTypeComboBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 24);
        this.RoomTypeComboBox.TabIndex = 25;
        // 
        // label14
        // 
        this.label14.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right;
        this.label14.AutoSize = true;
        this.label14.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.27F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label14.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(587, 270);
        this.label14.Name = "label14";
        this.label14.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(86, 16);
        this.label14.TabIndex = 26;
        this.label14.Text = "Passport No.";
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Anchor = System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right;
        this.textBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.27F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(672, 267);
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 21);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 27;
        // 
        // Reservation
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(204)))), ((int)(((byte)(204)))), ((int)(((byte)(255)))));
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label14);
        this.Controls.Add(this.RoomTypeComboBox);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label13);
        this.Controls.Add(this.NoOfDaysToStaytxt);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label12);
        this.Controls.Add(this.NoOfChildrentxt);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label11);
        this.Controls.Add(this.NoOfAdultstxt);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label10);
        this.Controls.Add(this.ReasonForStayingtxt);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label9);
        this.Controls.Add(this.LastNametxt);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Agetxt);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.FirstNametxt);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label8);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Addresstxt);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label7);
        this.Controls.Add(this.SexComboBox);
        this.Controls.Add(this.Occupationtxt);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label4);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label6);
        this.Controls.Add(this.MarriedcomboBox);
        this.Controls.Add(this.PhoneNoTxt);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label5);
        this.Name = "Reservation";
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 600);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox PhoneNoTxt;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label5;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox SexComboBox;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox FirstNametxt;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label7;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox Agetxt;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label8;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox MarriedcomboBox;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label4;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox LastNametxt;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox Occupationtxt;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label6;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox Addresstxt;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label9;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox ReasonForStayingtxt;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label10;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox NoOfAdultstxt;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label11;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox NoOfChildrentxt;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label12;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox NoOfDaysToStaytxt;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label13;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox RoomTypeComboBox;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label14;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;

}`

Answer (score 1):

Look like your Controls anchor isn't correct.

Could you post your code where you set the anchor values / dock values.

Comment: And here is my Dock code
<pre> usercontrol.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
<code>

Comment: Like i thought, you must edit the anchor values. 
Only "left" or "right" cause a centering of the Control, it will flow up and down and will only stay at his Location.X value. Anchor Left & Top or Right & Top should solve the problem

Comment: yeah i did that too but i just dont get it why is it hovering around and not being in place where i place it :(
Im so confused 
is it bcoz i hide my form border in my Main Windows and then use's user control and dock fill.
or what is it and i feel so lazy to proceed my project if this one does'nt get fix 
please anyone please try to solve it
and expert in the house coz i know its a simple problem but i cant fix it till now :(

Comment: I solved it all i did was add TableLayoutPanel and keep all my required label's and textbox's in Column and row and use anchor and fixed my problem :D